# Custom view longClickListener não responde

Tags: android, view

Estou tentando fazer com que minha view aceite cliques longos, mas nada acontece.

Eu olhei em outros posts similares, mas não encontrei nenhuma solução.

Alguma ideia do que pode estar ocorrendo?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.examples.danilofernandes.housemap.ViewForLayout
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:layout_width="100px"
android:layout_height="100px" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/button"
android:text="hello"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@id/layout"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

A classe:

```
public class ViewForLayout extends View {

...

public ViewForLayout(final Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
super(context, attrs);

setLongClickable(true);
setOnLongClickListener(new MyLongClickListenerClass());

....

}

public class MyLongClickListenerClass implements OnLongClickListener{

@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

    Toast.makeText(context, "I'm in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    return true;

}

}

}
```

Comment: retorna falso..

Comment: E use `Log.v("onLongClick", "Foi clicado");`

Comment: Tentei. Sem sucesso...

Comment: Tentou colocar algo aqui: `ALGUMA_VIEW.setOnLongClickListener(new MyLongClickListenerClass());`

Comment: Por exemplo: `btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn.setOnLongClickListenersetOnLongClickListener(new MyLongClickListenerClass());;`

Comment: `setLongClickable(true);` Para que setar `true` antes de clicar?

Comment: Quando me ocorre esse tipo de problema eu sempre debugo e vejo se o método está sendo chamado, 
Você ja debugou para ver se o método `ViewForLayout` está sendo executado?

Comment: tente tbm isso
`Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "I'm in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Answer (score 1):

As vezes esse problema é porque você não implementou o método `onMeasure` setando o tamanho real da sua **Custom View** usando o método `setMeasuredDimension`.

Por padrão o tamanho da `View` é igual ao tamanho do `Drawable` do background. Com isso eu acredito que o Android não esteja detectando toques na sua `View` e consequentemente chamando o método `onLongClick`.

Um exemplo de implementação do `onMeasure` seria:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int width = 0, height = 0;

    int suggestedWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int suggestedHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);

    // Not matter, i want the maximum width
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
        width = Math.max(getMinimumWidth(), suggestedWidth);
    } else {
        width = suggestedWidth;
    }

    if(heightMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY || heightMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
            height = Math.max(getMinimumHeight(), suggestedHeight);
        } else {
            height = suggestedHeight;
        }
    }

    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
}
```

Nessa minha implementação eu quero o maior tamanho disponível para a `View`.

Tenha em mente que os atributos: `layout_width` e `layout_height` influenciam no valor do *mode* tanto para altura quanto para largura.

Se não me engano com `layout_width` e `layout_height` você tem o `LayoutMode` sendo:

```
match_parent          -> LayoutMode.AT_MOST (MeasureSpec.getSize retorna o tamanho do pai)
wrap_content          -> LayoutMode.AT_MOST (MeasureSpec.getSize retorna 0)
0dp com layout_weight -> LayoutMode.AT_MOST (MeasureSpec.getSize retorna o tamanho restante para a View)

valor fixo            -> LayoutMode.EXACTLY (MeasureSpec.getSize retorna o tamanho exato)
```

**Como não tenho como testar no momento, não tenho total certeza dos valores acima. Qualquer erro eu posso corrigir**

Recomendo olhar esse documento http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html#layouteevent para mais detalhes.